# Simplify Makefile without changing its logic

Tags: makefile

I am wondering is there a way to refactor these 3 lines without changing the logic?

- scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} GrammarUtil.scala
- scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} FirstSpec.scala
- scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} FollowSpec.scala

Makefile

```
SPECS=FirstSpec FollowSpec
EXAMPLES_PATH=../..
ROOT_PATH=../${EXAMPLES_PATH}
SCALAV=2.12
APSLIB=${ROOT_PATH}/lib/aps-library-${SCALAV}.jar
SCALA_FLAGS=.:${APSLIB}
APS2SCALA=${ROOT_PATH}/bin/aps2scala

.PHONY: all
all: $(addsuffix .run, $(SPECS))

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.class grammar.scala first.scala follow.scala

# for anything.scala it compiles it to create class file
%.class: %.scala
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $<

# for anything.scala that does not already exist, it generates it
%.scala:
    ${APS2SCALA} -DCOT -p ${EXAMPLES_PATH}:${ROOT_PATH}/base $*

# for anything.run it needs to be compiled first before running
%.run: %.class
    scala -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $<)

# for GrammarUtil.class it needs to generate and compile grammar.class and then compile itself
GrammarUtil.class: grammar.class
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} GrammarUtil.scala
    # How to avoid above line: scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} GrammarUtil.scala

# for FirstSpec.class it needs to compile Spec.class, GrammarUtil.class and compile and then generate first.class
FirstSpec.class: Spec.class GrammarUtil.class first.class
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} FirstSpec.scala
    # How to avoid above line: scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} FirstSpec.scala

# for FollowSpec.class it needs to compile Spec.class, GrammarUtil.class and compile and then generate follow.class
FollowSpec.class: Spec.class GrammarUtil.class follow.class
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} FollowSpec.scala
    # How to avoid above line: scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} FollowSpec.scala
```

Comment: I do not know scala, but there are strange thinks in the Makefile: `%.class: %.scala`
    `scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $<` create x.class from x.scala; `GrammarUtil.class: grammar.class` create GrammarUtil.class from grammar.**class**  by using never referreced (in that recipe) GrammarUtil.**scala** and not using its prerequisity  grammar.**class** - if it really works, then there are dependencies hidden from Makefile, or some pregenerated files or sideeffects ...

Comment: ... On first look I would try change `$<` to `$^` to use all prequisities in `%.class: %.scala` and send output file to `$@` explicitely, then the `FollowSpec.class: Spec.class GrammarUtil.class follow.class` rules would need no body, as the body of `%.class: %.scala` would be used https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Rules.html#Multiple-Rules - if you think it may be possible, I can try make some commented Makefile, where you just should fix params for the `scalac` program to place output  in right file

Comment: The problem is if I remove `scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} FirstSpec.scala` how to tell it to use `%.class: %.scala` instead? we need to compile `FirstSpec.class` as well

Comment: If my answer worked, can you mark it as accepted (so the bounty would not came in vain)? If not, can you tell me, what problem you had?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, that the answer could look like that (put it to some clean directory and just run `make`, then look at those files with text editor/wiever):

```
SPECS=FirstSpec FollowSpec
EXAMPLES_PATH=../..
ROOT_PATH=../${EXAMPLES_PATH}
SCALAV=2.12
APSLIB=${ROOT_PATH}/lib/aps-library-${SCALAV}.jar
SCALA_FLAGS=.:${APSLIB}
APS2SCALA=${ROOT_PATH}/bin/aps2scala

.PHONY: all
all: $(addsuffix .run, $(SPECS))

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.class grammar.scala first.scala follow.scala

# for anything.scala it compiles it to create class file
#  Lets use ALL prequisities ($^) and create target by name (--output $@)
%.class: %.scala
    echo "scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $^ --output $@" > $@

# for anything.scala that does not already exist, it generates it
%.scala:
    echo "${APS2SCALA} -DCOT -p ${EXAMPLES_PATH}:${ROOT_PATH}/base $*" >$@

# for anything.run it needs to be compiled first before running
%.run: %.class
    echo "scala -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $(basename $<)" >$@

# for GrammarUtil.class it needs to generate and compile grammar.class and then compile itself
# for FirstSpec.class it needs to compile Spec.class, GrammarUtil.class and compile and then generate first.class
# for FollowSpec.class it needs to compile Spec.class, GrammarUtil.class and compile and then generate follow.class
GrammarUtil.class: grammar.class

FirstSpec.class: Spec.class GrammarUtil.class first.class

FollowSpec.class: Spec.class GrammarUtil.class follow.class
```

I have no scala, so I could not try it, but I let it put commands to create each file to that file for inspection - so it may be enought just to delete those `echo "` and `" >$@` to get the desired result.

Also I hope, that the `scalacp` command have some way to place output to explicitly named file - I used hypotetical `--output filename` switch for that. Or that is somehow get it from its first file parametr right (so the --outpu filename is not needed)

There are used 3 "tricks"

- to use all from dependencies there is `$^` variable
- to get name of target file is variable `$@`
- there can be more dependencies lines (like those 3 at bottom) and they use the same rule for the target, if it meets the same pattern